# Is it possible to test if object property uses a descriptor?

Tags: python, software-design, descriptor

I'm not convinced this is possible, but I thought I'd ask as I'm new to Python. Given an object with a property which its value is handled by a descriptor; is it possible to know that the given descriptor type was involved?

**Example Descriptor**:

```
class Column(object):
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label

    def __get__(self, obj, owner):
        return obj.__dict__.get(self.label)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        obj.__dict__[self.label] = value
```

**Test Object**:

```
class Test(object):
    name = Column("column_name")

    def add(self):
       print self.name.__class__
```

**Executing this**:

```
my_test = Test()
my_test.name = "myname"
my_test.add()
```

This gives: `<type 'str'>` which is the data type of the value "myname", is it possible to test for isinstance(self.name, Descriptor) - this returns false, but I want it to return true - or something similar?

**Edit** - Removed bug of old-style class on `Test`

Comment: Is `my_test.name` normally supposed to be assigned to a Column Object?

Comment: No, my_test.name is a property of the Test() object. The descriptor is to be used to make sure name is valid. I've used a descriptor rather than @property to reduce code, because it's going to be used in many places.  Ideally I want to know that my_test.name used the column descriptor. However, I'm not sure if this is possible..

Comment: @Matt Are you trying to determine what methods the descriptor is overriding or whether or not the object's class is a descriptor?

Comment: @Mike I'm trying to determine if a property used a specific descriptor to set the value.

Comment: well, I don't know what's your problem, but for me `foo = Column("bar") ; isinstance(foo,Column)` returns `True` (tested with py2 and py3) and `foo.__class__` is `<class '__main__.Column'>`

Comment: You're not actually using the descriptor. `Test` is an old-style class, so the accesses to `name` ignore the descriptor completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search the object's class and superclasses in method resolution order for the descriptor object:

```
def find_descriptor(instance, attrname):
    '''Find the descriptor handling a given attribute, if any.

    If the attribute named attrname of the given instance is handled by a
    descriptor, this will return the descriptor object handling the attribute.
    Otherwise, it will return None.
    '''
    def hasspecialmethod(obj, name):
        return any(name in klass.__dict__ for klass in type(obj).__mro__)
    for klass in type(instance).__mro__:
        if attrname in klass.__dict__:
            descriptor = klass.__dict__[attrname]
            if not (hasspecialmethod(descriptor, '__get__') or
                    hasspecialmethod(descriptor, '__set__') or
                    hasspecialmethod(descriptor, '__delete__')):
                # Attribute isn't a descriptor
                return None
            if (attrname in instance.__dict__ and
                not hasspecialmethod(descriptor, '__set__') and
                not hasspecialmethod(descriptor, '__delete__')):
                # Would be handled by the descriptor, but the descriptor isn't
                # a data descriptor and the object has a dict entry overriding
                # it.
                return None
            return descriptor
    return None
```

Comment: Yep, this works! It looks like going through the method resolution order is what I needed. I guess I was just reading the class of the value and not working my way through the mro. Thanks very much!

Comment: This function incorrectly returns `descriptor` instead of `None` for a `descriptor` with a `'__get__'`, `'__set__'`, or `'__delete__'` entry in its *instance* dictionary and without one in its class dictionary or its ancestors’. To correct this, the `hasattr` should be redefined to look up an entry on the class dictionary and its ancestors’ only, not on the instance dictionary. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @GéryOgam, That's because "the special method must be set on the class object itself in order to be consistently invoked by the interpreter".  Adding `__get__` etc. to the instance dictionary rather than the class description feels like an antipattern since the data model isn't guaranteed to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This checks if **fetching** an attribute will go through a descriptor. A descriptor can implement setting/deleting but not getting, so this can be useful if you want to be more specific than checking if any of the set/get/delete ops would be used.

This is based on the [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#invocation-from-an-instance), with modifications to just return the descriptor:

```py
def find_descriptor(obj, name:str):
    """ Find the descriptor, if any, an attribute retrieval on an instance would go through
    
        :param obj: instance object
        :param name: attribute which would be retrieved
        :returns: unbound descriptor ``__get__``, or ``None`` if no descriptor would be used
    """
    # lookup attribute in class hierarchy
    for base in type(obj).__mro__:
        base_dict = vars(base) 
        if name in base_dict:
            # we look for descriptor interface on value's class, not value itself
            value_clazz = type(base_dict[name])
            descr = getattr(value_clazz, '__get__', None)
            if descr:
                # data descriptor?
                if (hasattr(value_clazz, '__set__') or hasattr(value_clazz, "__delete__")):
                    return descr
                # instance variable can be used instead?
                if hasattr(obj, '__dict__') and name in vars(obj):
                    return
            # non-data descriptor?
            # if None, it indicates a class variable
            return descr
    # else, descriptor attribute not found
    # (could still be an instance variable, but we don't care about that)
```

Here is a simplified version, but not based on the official Python documentation:

```py
import inspect

def find_descriptor(obj, name:str):
    value = inspect.getattr_static(obj, name)
    descr = getattr(type(value), '__get__', None)
    if descr and not inspect.isdatadescriptor(value) and hasattr(obj, '__dict__') and name in vars(obj):
        return
    return descr
```

Comment: This will return `None` for an attribute where *setting* it goes through a descriptor, but *getting* it does not. (Makes sense, as you based it on a Python reimplementation of `__getattribute__`, and didn't look at `__setattr__`.) Example: https://ideone.com/FlXM8f

Comment: What behavior is more useful will depend on the use case, but I don't think "more correct" is an accurate description of the relationship between this code and my code. It's doing a different thing.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't understand you were testing for any of get/set/delete. In your example, fetching `x.x` is *not* handled by a descriptor. So just a warning to folks that testing any of get/set/delete may not be what you actually want (as was for my use case), as descriptor can be used for some but not other operations.